# Differentiate between different filesystem with the same name

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have written a code to analyze the file system statistics (say io,total no if files etc.) for RHEL. Now user delete the filesystem and create a new filesystem but with the same name.
Now my code is not able to differentiate between the file system and display data about FS which confuses user like which belongs to new and which belogs to old FS.
As my code is reading file system by its name. So if i get a unique id for the file system assigned by OS, it will help.
I expect OS will assign unique id every time file system create.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the [UUID](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Persistent_block_device_naming#By-uuid) of the filesystem, which should be unique for each filesystem.

Have a look at:

```
[root@server]# ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

If `/dev/disk/by-uuid` does not exist by default (e.g. on RHEL4), you can still query the UUID using `tune2fs` or `blkid`. For example:

```
[root@server]# tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | awk '/Filesystem UUID/{print $3}'
```

or

```
[root@server]# blkid /dev/sda1 | awk '{print $3}'
```

P.S. If you need to do a reverse mapping (find device based that has a specific UUID), you can use `findfs UUID=<the-uuid>`

Comment: Note that one *could* set an arbitrary UUID, so if you need *absolute reliability* then this is insufficient. If you only need it to work when noone is doing anything malicious (or stupid), then this should be sufficient.

Comment: Agreed. This is insufficient for mission critical or security driven purposes, but as a tool for convenience there's only so much one can do to guard against malicious use.

Comment: that's pretty much what I meant, but you put it much better.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be to store other identifying information about the filesystem besides it's name, for instance it's metadata, type, uuid of the partition it's on, etc...